# VS Code project code formatting using ESLint

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

I'm using VS Code for a React project and have VS Code configured to *format on save* and to *Require a 'prettierconfig' to format* (the *Prettier: Require Config* setting from the VSCode Prettier [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)). I also have the ESLint plugin enabled.

That seems to mean my project's *.prettierrc* config file drives the formatting on save and *.eslintrc.json* provides linting warnings. But in at least one case (below) some formatting issues are left unresolved on save.

The code below, as formatted, shows *eslint(indent)* squiggly warnings in VS Code. Upon save (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>), some get resolved, but some do not.

Specifically, the incorrect indent spacing of the first `<div>` gets fixed on save and that *eslint(indent)* warning disappears. However, the later *eslint(indent)* warnings do NOT get resolved on save. But they DO, however, get resolved when (on Windows) I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>P</kbd>, then find and click the "ESLint: Fix all auto-fixable Problems".

When I save the file again those changes are reverted and the warning appears again.

So "format on save" applies different formatting than "ESLint: Fix all auto-fixable Problems". Is there a way to reconcile these? I would like **all** the *eslint(indent)* issues to resolve on save.

Does anyone know what ESLint settings drive "ESLint: Fix all auto-fixable Problems"?

```
const MyModule = () => {
  ...   

  return (
    // "eslint(indent)" warning on next line gets resolved on save
  <div>
      {!menus.find(function(permission) {
        return permission.level === 'ADMIN';
      }) ? (
        // "eslint(indent)" warnings below DO NOT get resolved on save
        // ... but they DO get resolved on "ESLint: Fix all auto-fixable problems"
        // ... then they reappear on save
        <div>
          <Redirect to="/" />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <Results />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyModule;
```

My .eslintrc.json contents:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended",
    "prettier",
    "prettier/react"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "react/prop-types": 0,
    "no-console": 1,
    "no-control-regex": 0,
    "indent": ["warn", 2],
    "quotes": ["warn", "single"],
    "space-in-parens": 1,
    "prefer-destructuring": 0,
    "prefer-const": 0
  },
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "plugins": ["react", "import", "jsx-a11y"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    }
  }
}
```

My .prettierrc:

```
{
  "useTabs": false,
  "printWidth": 120,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "singleQuote": true
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Like the other posted suggested, I use a setup where eslint runs prettier for me. I already had prettier disabled for my js/ts files so I knew that wasn't the issue. It turns out it was the built in formatter for vscode and turning off `editor.formatOnSave` fixed the issue.

My project's settings.json. This disables the formatter only for typescript files. Eslint will still fix your files as long as you have the eslint auto fix settings enabled.

```
{
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
  },
  "[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
  }
}
```

Rather than turning off formatOnSave, you could instead set the default formatter to eslint:

```
{
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"
  },
  "[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"
  }
}
```

Here are the rest of my settings just for reference.

My user settings.json

```
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": true,
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  },
  "eslint.validate": [
    "javascript",
    "javascriptreact",
    "typescript",
    "typescriptreact"
  ],
  "prettier.disableLanguages": [
    "javascript",
    "javascriptreact",
    "typescript",
    "typescriptreact",
    "markdown"
  ]
}
```

.eslintrc

```
{
  "root": true,
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "project": "tsconfig.json",
    "warnOnUnsupportedTypeScriptVersion": false
  },
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "jest", "prettier"],
  "extends": [
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": [
      "error",
      {
        "tabWidth": 2,
        "useTabs": false,
        "semi": false,
        "singleQuote": true,
        "trailingComma": "all",
        "printWidth": 110
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: `Rather than turning off formatOnSave, you could instead set the default formatter to eslint:` I made these changes but ran into an issue about ESLint not knowing how to format ts/js files. [The fix is to turn on an ESLint extension setting to make ESLint a formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71884347/61624).

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using both prettier and eslint formatters, just use the eslint formatter and add your prettier options inside your eslintrc file. [Here's an example](https://github.com/alex-wilmer/prettieslint/blob/master/.eslintrc.js#L6)

https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html

```
// .eslintrc.json

...
"rules": {
 "prettier/prettier": [
    1,
    {
      "useTabs": false,
      "printWidth": 120,
      "tabWidth": 2,
      "singleQuote": true
    }
  ]
}
...
```

Comment: I like this idea, but it doesn't seem to address my issue. In fact, when I change to this approach (remove .prettierrc in favor of adding the above .eslintrc.json rule), then saving (Ctl+S) in VS Code no longer seems to apply any formatting rules to my file at all. I'd like VS Code to continue formatting my files on save, but in a way consistent with my ESLint config file and that does not leave unresolved warnings.

Comment: it sounds like you do not have the `format on save` checkbox checked in your eslint packages settings

Comment: Hm, I have `Editor: Format On Save` checked. Is there a separate ESLint `format on save`?

Comment: ah VSCode is wacky. you might need to edit your settings config. My answer is still relevant but try to also follow this https://medium.com/@pgivens/write-cleaner-code-using-prettier-and-eslint-in-vscode-d04f63805dcd

Comment: Actually, there is a `Eslint: Auto Fix On Save` setting, which also affects this formatting. I didn't notice that before. Maybe it's new, but not sure. I also notice the `Require a 'prettierconfig' to format` seems to have disappeared from the VS Code settings UI.

Comment: I already have this setup but yet I also have discrepancies between saving the file and using the "fix auto fixable problems" command