# Extension 'eslint' is configured as formatter but it cannot format 'JavaScript'-files

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, code-formatting, vscode-eslint

I am experiencing an intermittent problem with ESLint in VS Code. When saving a file, instead of formatting it, this message shows in the status bar:

[image]

Apparently no one has ever reported this message on Google.

When I say it is intermittent, it was working fine, then the computer (MBP) crashed, and on restarting this is the situation. It has happened previously, but I don't recall what I did to fix it.

The app is a fairly complex Vue-based app based on a pre-configured template. In package.json:

```
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.13",

    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.31.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.14.0",
```

In the VS Code workspace file:

```
        "editor.codeLens": true,
        "eslint.format.enable": true,
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
          "source.fixAll.eslint": true,
        },
        "[javascript]": {
            "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"
        },
        "[vue]": {
            "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"
        },
        "eslint.validate": [
            "javascript"
        ],
        "debug.javascript.usePreview": true,
        "debug.javascript.usePreviewAutoAttach": true,
        "[jsonc]": {
            "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"
        },
```

I'm really not sure how to proceed to understand why vscode-eslint is reporting that it can't format JavaScript files.

EDIT

[This issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/1355) regarding TypeScript gives some hints. It seems this error can result when the ESLint server is restarting or the extension host is under a lot of stress.

In my project now, most files are formatting fine, although one consistently fails. That file is called `eslint.js` and is part of a build process, running eslint - I don't totally understand the configuration. I suspect that saving this file somehow causes eslint to be run/reloaded, and while that is happening, eslint-vscode tries to also run it and fails.

Comment: I had the same issue. To solve I used the Command Palette, clicked to format, got the same message, but VS Code gave me the option to configure -- which I did and it works now ‍♂️

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This can happen for a variety of reasons. The eslint output logs will tell you the issue.

[image]

In my case the settings field `configFile` was changed to `overrideConfigFile`

Comment: In my case, I had set an invalid rule on my `eslintrc.js`. just check the Eslint errors. thanks @chantey

Comment: If it helps : for me, problem was caused by a trailing comma in `.estlintrc`

Comment: My ESLint output log shows no errors, but I'm still having this problem :(.

Comment: This only outputs logs in some cases. Also, this tab doesn't usually output anything unless there's an error of this kind. Useful logs are off by default.

Answer (score 56):

I was fighting with this for a while, turns out you need to head to `Settings`, under `User` go to `Extensions > ESLint`, scroll down to `Format:Enable` and enable `ESLint` as a formatter.

Settings:

[image: Settings Screenshot]

Comment: For me this is already the case and I still receive the error.

Comment: For me disabling this setting and then re-enabling helped

Comment: @kamil-now that did not help me

Answer (score 6):

I was actually experiencing the same problem and I only needed to remove the `.eslintignore` file, which only contained this line:

```
.eslintrc.js
```

You could simply comment that line too.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 4):

In my case this was even simpler than the other answers here: I forgot to create a `.eslintrc.js` file for this project.
So running `npx eslint --init` fixed it. Copying the file from another project would also work.

Hope this helps someone like me googling this error and getting to this question.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was:

```bash
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean --force
npm install
```

Close VScode and then re-open

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this is because the eslint version installed is too old. It seems that some old version just cann't format `javascript`.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it seemed as if StandardJS was trying to lint everything in my `node_modules` folder. The error went away and linting started working again after adding a `standard.ignore` property to my `package.json`, followed by reloading VSCode:

```json
{
  "name": "foo",
  "devDependencies": {
    "standard": "^16.0.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    // stuff...
  },
  "standard": {
    "ignore": [
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

No idea why this behavior didn't happen automatically...

---

**UPDATE:**
I previously had installed `eslint` alongside `standard`, which may have been the root cause. My original install command was `npm install standard eslint`, which installed the latest version of `eslint`, v8.x.x. However, `standard` (at the time of writing) depends on `eslint` v7.x.x, causing a conflict.

The fix:

```sh
~$ npm uninstall eslint # remove eslint from package.json
~$ rm -rf node_modules  # remove node_modules
~$ npm install          # get fresh installation
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable ESLint extension
2. Reload window
3. Enable ESLint extension
4. Do `npm i eslint -g`, also install ESLint on the project using `npm i eslint -D`
5. Make sure VSCode `settings.json` does not have another default default formatter for JavaScript

```json
{
  "eslint.enable": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
  "editor.formatOnType": true,
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
  }
}
```

6. Reload window

That worked for me

Answer (score 0):

for me it was because the .eslintrc file had an error inside, I had a coma on the end of a line in a JSON that make the file unreadable. check the log of eslint maybe it tell the issue

Answer (score 0):

I see the Eslint log that show that:
The language client requires VS Code version ^1.82.0 but received version 1.73.0
Then I update to the lastest version to resolve problem

Answer (score -2):

I edited my user settings.json. Added this.

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint":true 
},
```

Answer (score -2):

add these lines in your settings.json

```
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.fixAll.eslint": true,
            "source.addMissingImports": true
        },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).